# How can i have at sign in property name in c# Class

Tags: c#, public

I am implementing a specific use case. We have requirement to have @ sign in our serialize object. Is there any way we can have @ sign in property name?

My class looks like

```
public class Test
{

    public string @name
}
```

When I serialize the class, I need value as "@name" : "value of property" Is there any way I can achieve this?

I already tried [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: What are you serializing to?  XML? JSON?

Comment: What are you trying to serialize the class to? Jinx @DStanley. You owe me a Coke!

Comment: I don't think either XML or JSON support elements that begin with `@` (C# doesn't either...)

Comment: In C#, `@` can be used at the beginning of property names, it is useful if you need a property with a name that is normally a keyword, e.g. `public int @if { get; set; }`. However, the `@` will not actually be a part of the name, it's just a compiler trick. If you look at the property via reflection, its name will be "if". So I think you'll have to do the serialization manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include a literal `@` in the property name.

In the C# Language Specification following the link you listed describing the grammar of valid identifiers, it says that an identifier starts with either a `@`, a `_`, or a

**letter-character**:

- A Unicode character of classes Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, or Nl
- A unicode-escape-sequence representing a character of classes Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, or Nl

The `@` sign is in Unicode category "Punctuation, Other" [Po] and so cannot be at the start of the property name (nor anywhere in the property name per the rest of the specification).

The prefix `@` is not actually part of the identifier.